# Throwing and catching exceptions #2

Tags: c#, exception, catch-block

I've a console application that zips files and then send them via email. It does that every hour. 
I wanted to know what kind of exceptions should I handle ? Let say if there's no network available when the process starts. What exception will I get then ? And what can be the other ways this can fail. So basically I'm trying to figure out what exceptions I should catch.

I got something like this

```
try
{
    // zips files and send email
}      
catch(System.Net.Mail.SmtpException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.toString());
}
catch(exception e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, the libraries you're using will come with documentation that will list all of the types of exceptions that can be thrown, if not then you'll have to use a tool like Reflector to inspect the methods you're using to find their thrown exceptions.

For example, the `SmtpClient.Send` method (as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx ) lists these exceptions:

- ArgumentNullException
- InvalidOperationException
- ObjectDisposedException
- SmtpException
- SmtpFailedRecipientsException

Remember to catch exceptions in descending order of derivity, i.e. catch `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` before `SmtpException` because `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` derives from `SmtpException`.

Comment: Note, that caller of `SmtpClient.Send` should never catch `ArgumentNullException`, `InvalidOperationException` and `ObjectDisposedException`. When these exceptions are raised, this means errors in caller code.

Comment: Also, never "swallow" exceptions - log them if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the MSDN pages to view what types of exceptions certain methods or constructors will throw from .NET libraries. Such as, for the [SmtpClient.Send method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it throws the following exceptions:

- ArgumentNullException
- InvalidOperationException
- ObjectDisposedException
- SmtpException
- SmtpFailedRecipientsException

There is also a link of common exception types that you may be interested in located [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/03/27/402801.aspx).